# Populating a table from a list

Tags: python, list, loops

I want to populate the first N rows of a table with the elements from a list.
Right now i'm using this(it fills the first 5 rows of each column until it runs out of elements from the list) and it works:

```
l=list(range(1,20))

col=0
row=0

for x in l:
    button=QPushButton()
    layout.addWidget(button,row,col)
    row+=1
    if row%5==0:
        col+=1
        row=0
```

The example is with pyqt but that's irrelevant. 
***Question is***: *how do i do it **without** initiating those 2 variables at the beginning: col and row* **outside** the for loop, it's really ugly and as i understood from reading 123141241 stackoverflow posts so far, it's not "pythonic". Thx!

Comment: To do `l = list(range(1,20))` first and then only iterate over `l` - this is what's not Pythonic. It also wastes the computer's resources.

Comment: i used l=list... for the example. In real life i have a list which is stored in a json file and read at the program launch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for x in range(1,20):
    row = x%5
    col = x // 5
    button=QPushButton()
    layout.addWidget(button,row,col)
```

Comment: Or simply: `col = x // 5`.

Comment: Thanks @ForceBru :)

Comment: Consider using `col, row = divmod(x, 5)` to make it more concise.